# Limit tbl_uvregression() output based on p-value threshold

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am running a univariate logistic regression for a model feature selection and want to be able to only display significant variables in a chart. Is there an argument within tbl_uvregression() that would allow me to only display variable that have a p-value < 0.05. Code below:

```
tbl <- df %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    y = diabetes,
    exponentiate = TRUE 
  )%>%
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p()
```

I tried to use the include argument to manually set the variables that were bolded (so as to signify variables with a p-value < 0.05). Surely there's a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the table in returned `tbl_uvregression` object, either directly  through `tbl$table_body` or by using `gtsummary::modify_table_body()`.
Or just use `gtsummary::filter_p()` :

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl <- mtcars[6:11] %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    y = vs,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p() 

tbl %>% 
  as_kable(format = "pipe")
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wt | 32 | 0.15 | 0.03, 0.49 | **<0.001** |
| qsec | 32 | 22.7 | 4.05, 582 | **<0.001** |
| am | 32 | 2.00 | 0.48, 8.76 | 0.3 |
| gear | 32 | 1.79 | 0.68, 5.14 | 0.2 |
| carb | 32 | 0.27 | 0.09, 0.58 | **<0.001** |

```r
tbl %>% 
  filter_p() %>% 
  as_kable(format = "pipe")
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wt | 32 | 0.15 | 0.03, 0.49 | **<0.001** |
| qsec | 32 | 22.7 | 4.05, 582 | **<0.001** |
| carb | 32 | 0.27 | 0.09, 0.58 | **<0.001** |

<sup>Created on 2023-09-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>